# Qt - output of processes all written at once in TextEdit

Tags: qt, qprocess

I have a window in which I want to execute multiple processes sequentially and after each process is finished I want to write its output in a TextEdit widget. My code is as follows:

`

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++){
    ui->textEdit->append(QString("Running test: ") + QString::number(i + 1));
    this->runningToolProcess = new QProcess();
    connect(this->runningToolProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(rightMessage()));
    connect(this->runningToolProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(wrongMessage()));
    connect(this->runningToolProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(processFinished()));
    this->runningToolProcess->start(
        QString::fromStdString("/path/to/executable"),
        testParameters
    );
    this->runningToolProcess->waitForFinished();
}`
```

The rightMessage and wrongMessage functions are as follow:

```
`
void RunningToolWindow::rightMessage()
{
    QByteArray strdata = this->runningToolProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
    ui->textEdit->setTextColor(Qt::black);
    ui->textEdit->append(strdata);
}
void RunningToolWindow::wrongMessage()
{
    QByteArray strdata = this->runningToolProcess->readAllStandardError();
    ui->textEdit->setTextColor(Qt::red);
    ui->textEdit->append(strdata);
}`
```

The problem I have is that all the output is written at once after all the tests have finished executing, instead of their outputs being shown continuously as the tests progress. I tried inserting a delay after each test is ran but that did not seem to solve the problem.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop blocks Qt's event loop which is why the GUI is not updating.
You could use `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` once per loop iteration to update the GUI:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++){
    ...
    this->runningToolProcess->waitForFinished();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
}
```

Alternatively you could start the next process in your `processFinished()` slot. For that you would need a counter as a member variable that tracks the number of previously launched processes to find out if another process must be launched.